# Mongodb $min value is greater than $max sometimes

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm fetching date from mongo database and returns  `$first`,`$max`, `$min`,   and `$last`, however something very unusual happens - `$min` is greater than `$max`. Here's my code:

```
let Lowestdate = await ETHMongo.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { createdAt: { $gte: new Date(last), $lte: new Date(NEW) } },
  },    
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,

      minFee_doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
      minFee: { $min: "$one" },

      firstFee: { $first: "$one" },
      lastFee: { $last: "$one" },
      maxFee: { $max: "$one" },
    },
  },
]).then((result) => {});
```

Any solution?
[image: Table Heading]
[image: Wrong results]

Comment: can you add a sample database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "numbers" are saved as `string`, in string comparison `"99" > "1000000"`.

Luckily you can solve this very easily, just cast the string to number using [$toInt](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,

        minFee_doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" },
        minFee: { $min: {$toInt: "$one"} },

        firstFee: { $first: "$one" },
        lastFee: { $last: "$one" },
        maxFee: { $max: {$toInt: "$one"} },
    },
}
```